# When converting an answer to an edit for the question change the reference numbers

Tags: feature-request, convert

I converted an answer to an edit for the question, on [Is there a way to display an 'All' link following the alphabetic glossary with Views 7.x-3.x?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/22494/is-there-a-way-to-display-an-all-link-following-the-alphabetic-glossary-filter) The edit didn't change the reference number used for the links, with the effect of getting what shown in the screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

As consequence of this, the image was not visible anymore.

In such cases, the reference numbers should be increased to avoid any conflict.